# WP CLI - Pass Query / URL Variable to Cron?

Tags: variables, wp-cron, wp-cli, query-variable

Is there a way to pass URL / Query variables when you run:
`wp cron event run` using WP CLI? I have a specific event and ID I want to pass to it but don't know if it is possible or how to pass GET ($_GET) variables to the command line.

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why you would need GET variables? Is there no particular reason that Job couldn't be done as a separate WP CLI command with CLI parameters?

Comment: I want to run a longer running task that breaks up the number of tasks into smaller chunks that get triggered every few minutes. I want to tell it to trigger that specific trigger command with the ID of the task I want to run. It is done that way to as not to interrupt or block the existing WP Cron. For instance if I run http://example.com/wp-cron.php?key=xyz&id=32&action=trigger - I want to pass the key, id, and action variables.